# Can we perform CRUD operation by using apache ignite Data streamer?

Tags: ignite

I just wanted to know whethere we can perform CRUD operation by using apache ignite data streamer or not using java.

Answer (score 0):

You can do create, update or delete operations by using custom Java StreamReceiver. Read operations are tricky since Data Streamer does not return custom result of operations. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: One more question, Can we perform transaction while using ignite data streamer?

Comment: Yes, but only per entry, using StreamReceiver.